# Expected size of largest connected component in a random k-out digraph?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Given a digraph with n vertices and kn edges, where each vertex has k out-neighbors randomly chosen at uniform without loops, how would I go about figuring out the expected value of the size of the largest weakly connected component without explicitly summing over every graph?